# Reading a value in a physical address via the kernel

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

I'm working on an old linux operating system which has one kernel for all processes (it basically an exo-kernel type).
While implementing debugging features from user space, I would like to disassemble other's processes commands. Therefore, I have created a system-call which takes the virtual address at the target process and prints it's value in it (so I can disassemble the bytes).
My idea was to switch to the target's pgdir, call a pagewalk and then access the data in the physical address pointer. I get a kernel panic while trying to access the later.
If I'm switching to the target's process and then access the virtual address (without pagewalk), the bytes of the command are printed without any problem (with printf("%04x", *va) for example).

My question is - why does the virtual address contain the actual command but the physical address don't (and why does it panic?)

Thank you!

Comment: "and then access the data in the physical address pointer." - Whatever address you pass to the CPU for dereference, CPU will treat this address as **virtual** one. For read the information at **physical** address you need to have this address **mapped**, and use corresponded **virtual** address in the instruction.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you! I think I got my problem. Instead of doing the pagewalk, I should switch the page directory (load it to the appropriate register) and then access the virtual address. Because it's mapped, it will print the content of it.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is an XY-answer ... I'm aware I'm not answering *your question* ('how to twiddle with hardware MMU setup to read ... memory somewhere') but I'm suggesting a solution to *your stated problem* (how to read from another process' address space).

Linux provides a facility to do what you ask for - read memory from another process' address space - via the use of `ptrace()`,

```
   PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, PTRACE_PEEKDATA
          Read a word at the address addr in the tracee's memory, returning
          the word as the result of the ptrace() call.  Linux does not have
          separate text and data address spaces, so these two requests are 
          currently equivalent.  (data is ignored; but see NOTES.)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ptrace+PTRACE_PEEKDATA for some references ?